# Add attributes to "system parameters" (e.g. those added via CmdletBinding / SupportsPaging)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Is it possible to add attributes to system parameters?

e.g. say I have a function that supports paging:

```
function Get-MyPage {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsPaging = $true)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Something
    )
    process {
        #...
    }
}
```

I could give the `$Something` parameter an alias, or add validation like so:

```
[Alias('Thing')]
[ValidateSetAttribute('A','B','C')]
[string]$Something
```

However, is it possible to do this with those "system parameters" which are added through CmdletBinding / SupportsPaging?

i.e. How would I implement the following, given I don't explicitly define the `First` parameter?

```
[Alias('PageSize')]
[ValidateRange(1, 250)]
#[int]$First #This parameter exists because SupportsPaging = $true
```

---

Tried:

```
[PSAlias]$FirstAlias = New-Object 'PSAlias' -ArgumentList @('PageSize', 'First', ([string].Name))
(Get-Command -Name 'Get-MyPage').Parameters['First'].Aliases.Add($FirstAlias)
(Get-Command -Name 'Get-MyPage').Parameters['First'].Aliases #this shows it's been successfully added
Get-MyPage "hello" -Skip 3 -IncludeTotalCount -PageSize 4 #this shows it doesn't work
#Get-MyPage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PageSize'.

(Get-Command -Name 'Get-MyPage').Parameters['First'].Aliases.Clear()
(Get-Command -Name 'Get-MyPage').Parameters['First'].Aliases.Add('PageSize')
Get-MyPage "hello" -PageSize 2 -Skip 3 -IncludeTotalCount
#Get-MyPage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PageSize'

(Get-Command -Name 'Get-MyPage').Parameters['First'].Attributes.Add((New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.AliasAttribute' -ArgumentList 'First'))
#Get-MyPage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PageSize'.
```

---

Full Cmdlet Code used for the above

```
function Get-MyPage {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsPaging = $true)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Something
    )
    process {
        [hashtable]$splat = @{}
        if ($PSCmdlet.PagingParameters.Skip) {$splat.Add('Skip', $PSCmdlet.PagingParameters.Skip)}
        if ($PSCmdlet.PagingParameters.First -ne [System.UInt64]::MaxValue) {$splat.Add('First', $PSCmdlet.PagingParameters.First)}
        $Something.ToCharArray() | select @splat 
    }
    end {
        if ($PSCmdlet.PagingParameters.IncludeTotalCount) { $PSCmdlet.PagingParameters.NewTotalCount($Something.ToCharArray().Count, 1.0)}
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do a binary module you can probably use either reflection or a [typedescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) to decorate the inherited `First` property with an `AliasAttribute`, but I don't think PowerShell itself has any syntax that would allow you to do so

Comment: Related...  For setting a default value there's: `$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Get-MyPage:First",5)`, which can be added immediately after the function's definition.